# animate div up and down

Tags: jquery

I am just making a panel, ( div ) that has cookie, and can be opened or closed. 
I would like though to animate the div open or closed on click.

The code I have so far is:

```
var state;
window.onload=function() {
   obj=document.getElementById('closeable');
   state=(state==null)?'hide':state;
   obj.className=state;

   document.getElementById('setup').onclick=function() {
      obj.className=(obj.className=='show')?'hide':'show';
      state=obj.className;
      setCookie();

      return false;
   }
}

function setCookie() {
   exp=new Date();
   plusMonth=exp.getTime()+(31*24*60*60*1000);
   exp.setTime(plusMonth);
   document.cookie='State='+state+';expires='+exp.toGMTString();
}

function readCookie() {
   if(document.cookie) {
      state=document.cookie.split('State=')[1];
   }
}
readCookie();
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understood your question right. But, based on what I have understood, I have put together a fiddle to achieve what you want. Have a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/mvelaga/de4FE/1

**Edit:**

Updating the fiddle to address the scenario mentioned in comments

http://jsfiddle.net/mvelaga/de4FE/2/

Comment: Perfect Mahesh, I wish you lived in Brisbane. We would employ you immediately. Great work mate, thanks again ( second time you have assisted us ) regards

Comment: I have the hide show event initated by : <div>
    <a id="setup" href="javascript:;">show/hide welcome panel</a>
   </div>
I would like to change message dependant on the show or hide state . Any suggestions

Comment: Then you're better off using my code -- I've updated it for your scenario.  You want to use the `text()` method.

Comment: @422: I have updated the answer with an updated fiddle to address the scenario that you mentioned. Also, as @typeof mentioned, he is doing the dynamic text toggling in his answer as well.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh. On page refresh tho, cookie isnt set. I am missing something lolol

Comment: Hope, I could help out further. But, need to catch some sleep. Later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using jQuery because you've tagged it.

Try:
// on dom ready

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var panel = $('#closable');
    var state = 'hide';

    $('#setup').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(state == 'hide') {
            // you can use the animate() or 
            // fadeIn()/fadeOut methods, too
            // depending on desired effect
            panel.slideDown();
            $(this).text('Hide');
            state = 'show';
        } else
            panel.slideUp();
            $(this).text('Show');
            state = 'hide';
        }
        setCookie();
    })
    function setCookie() {
         ...
    }
    function readCookie() {
         ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, It looks economical on code lol. But how to initialise it within the html>? and set cookie state ?

Comment: The document loads and the click handler is attached to your show/hide link.  The cookie functions you had should still work, so I didn't include them.  Will edit to show you where you should place them.

Comment: thanks , because Mahesh code doesnt now set cookie,. Not sure why, doesnt on the fiddle either, but guessing thats cause of the onload event

Comment: To be honest, for cookies setting and reading, I rely on this great jQuery plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Thanks Typeof, will check this out and test your code. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [JQuery toogle+slide](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggle/)?